# Перенос textView из одного LinearLayout в другой

Tags: java, android

У меня есть два LinearLayout в которых есть несколько textView, первое поле имеет определённый размер. Есть ли возможность по заполнению первого поля, переносить textView во второе поле?

UPD: На основе предложенного варианта реализовал такой метод:

```
public void changeParent(TextView tv){
    FrameLayout flCoverBook = findViewById(R.id.flCoverBook);
    LinearLayout llTextView1 = findViewById(R.id.llTextView1);
    if (llTextView1.getHeight() <= flCoverBook.getHeight()) {
        ((LinearLayout) tv.getParent()).removeView(tv);
        ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llTextView1)).addView(tv); 
        contentFrameLayout.invalidate(); 
    }
}
```

Но при использовании он не отработал так необходимо, так как после добавления textView в поле (layout) размер поля оставался прежним, пробовал обновлять его разными методами:

```
llTextView1.removeAllViews();
llTextView1.requestLayout();
llTextView1.invalidate();
contentFrameLayout.invalidate()l;
lTextView1.refreshDrawableState();
```

Даже прибегал к достаточно специфичным:

```
lTextView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
lTextView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

lTextView1.removeAllViews();
lTextView1.refreshDrawableState();
```

и т.д.

Одним реальным решением нашёл вариант получения размера поля, затем с каждым добавленным textView добавлять его размер (высоту). Но такой подход не учитывает количество строк занимаемым textView и это в принципе костыль чем реальная реализация.

Заполнение полей выполняется по callback-у и экран обновляется методом:

```
contentFrameLayout.invalidate();
```

После всех этих манипуляций у меня сложилось впечатление, что с элементами на экране можно работать только после его заполнения и визуализации, а не в момент заполнения.

Comment: первое поле чего? поясните, что имеете ввиду.

Comment: считать количество символов и при достижении определенного количества проводить манипуляции

Comment: Вам вот эта либа нужна: https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Comment: @Jarvis_J, под словом поле я имел ввиду LinearLayout. У меня есть макет на нём находится картинка, рядом с ней есть LinearLayout в котором содержатся textView. Эти textView могут быть удалены, в зависимости от наличия той или иной информации. Количество информации в textView "условно" может быть не ограничено, соответственно когда они занимают высоту больше картинки, получается не красиво. Вот я и хочу добавить ниже ещё одну LinearLayout, в которую переносить textView. А реализовывать другие поля имеет смысл только если полностью меня шаблон.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос: напишите функцию, которая будет вызываться каждый раз при изменении текста в `TextView`:

```
void changeParent(TextView tv){
        if (tv.getText().length()>limit) {
        //или
        if (tv.getHeight()>img.getHeight()) {
            ((LinearLayout) tv.getParent()).removeView(tv);
            ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.secondLL)).addView(tv);
        }
}
```

И передавайте туда ваш `TextView`.

`((LinearLayout) tv.getParent())` и `((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.secondLL))` можно определить в переменные заранее.

Либо, напишите кастомный `TextView`, в котором на `setText(...)` эта функция будет вызываться через `interface`.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Воспользовался вашим решением, немного изменив его под свои условия, где получилось:   changeParent(TextView tv){
        FrameLayout flCoverBook = findViewById(R.id.flCoverBook);
        LinearLayout llTextView1 = findViewById(R.id.llTextView1);
        if (llTextView1.getHeight() <= flCoverBook.getHeight()) {
            ((LinearLayout) tv.getParent()).removeView(tv);
            ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llTextView1)).addView(tv);
            contentFrameLayout.invalidate();
     }}    и вылезла очередная проблема, размер полей всегда одинаков. Как можно решить?

Comment: размер - это высота? сделайте и посмотрите в логах, она не 0?

Comment: нет она не ноль, размер (высота) картинки (поля содержащую) равна 270px, высота поля с textView 171px, при добавлении в него новых textView его размер не изменен. Высота этого поля установлена "wrap_content". Пробовал после каждого добавления обновлять "корневое" поле, поле содержащее textView и их вместе, разными методами: llTextView1.removeAllViews(); llTextView1.requestLayout(); llTextView1.invalidate(); contentFrameLayout.invalidate()l; lTextView1.refreshDrawableState(), безрезультатно. Нужно уточнить,что заполнение полей идёт по CallBack-у и экран обновляется:contFrameLayout.invalidate();

Comment: Единственное рабочее решение которое на данный момент у меня получилось это получить высоту поля, и при каждом добавлении textView, добавлять размер textView к размеру поля. Но такой метод больше похож на костыли и есть другая проблема, при такой реализации не учитывается высота textView с конечным её содержимым.

Comment: Если вы не получили ответа на свой вопрос, лучше добавляйте код в вопрос с меткой, например, "upd:". Во-первых, здесь его тяжело читать, во-вторых, кто-то еще сможет понять в чем проблема и подсказать решение, в-третьих, если у кого-то возникнет подобный вопрос, ему будет проще найти ответ.